# Java beginnings using Netbeans

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I'm just about starting to learn Java. Reading about, I installed Netbeans.

Running Apache Netbeans IDE 11.2. 
The Java version is 13.0.2.

I'm promptly follow the [Quickstart guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html) on the netbeans website.

File>>New project>> Java >> Java Application.

Errhmm, I don't have this 'Java' option. All I have is

[image: menu option]

So what's the difference between Java & Java with Maven/Cradle/Ant . At this point in time, I intend to start with basics of Java programming and then move on from there. SO which option am I meant to be starting with? If I'm missing Java, how can I add it ? Going through the installation procedures didn't give me any option to choose from.

p:s - this is all running on Mac OS Catalina

Comment: When you want to use libraries/dependencies (code already written for your use case), then you'll ideally want a build system (e.g. Maven). These allow you to specify and use those dependencies without having to manually download and link them, you just specify what dependency you want. For just getting started, you don't need Maven/etc but there's nothing stopping you from using it

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with any of `Java with ...` option. I use `Java with Ant` option.

**Maven**, **Gradle**, **Ant** are build-tool addons i.e. they provide additional support if you intend to use any of these as your build tool.

When you choose `Java with Ant` option, it will let you create, compile, debug and run your Java programs without requiring anything additional. After using this option, you will get an interface as shown in the screenshot given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maven, Gradle and Ant are build tool which allows you to compile, unit test, package and (if you like) even deploy your Java applications (they do support other languages btw).

I suggest you to start with one of those (Maven is very popular and probably a little bit easier than the others) instead of relying on your Java IDE specific features.

Once you master a build tool you can change IDE (IntelliJ is also a very good option ;-)) and will still work as before. You also find plenty of resources and help (like Stackoverflow) if you need hit some problems.

Best of luck!